# Can console log fetched array but cant get the values

Tags: javascript, fetch, svelte, sveltekit

So I can call the variable "teams" and see the data fine but I can't get the values from it in my {#each} block. I know its not part of the "fixtures" variable I'm iterating through and tbh that's probably the issue.

Does anyone know how I can get the actual values within "teams" instead of getting 'undefined' or a better way of fetching multiple arrays within themselves? (ill put the example at the bottom)

my +page.svelte

```
<script>

export let data;

const { fixtures } = data;

const teams = fixtures.flatMap(fixtures => fixtures.participants)

console.log(teams)

</script>

<div class="flex flex-col absolute top-[0] right-0 w-[85vw] p-6">
    
    <div class="">
        {#each fixtures as fixture}
            <p>{fixture.name}</p>
            <div class="">{fixture.home_score}{fixture.away_score}</div>
            <p>{teams.short_code}</p>
        {/each}
    </div>

</div>
```

+page.server.js

```
 export const load = async () => {

    const fetchList= async () => {
    const url = `https://api.sportmonks.com/v3/football/schedules/seasons/19734?api_token=${process.env.API_KEY}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json()
    return data.data.flatMap(data => data.rounds.map(rounds => rounds.fixtures)).flat()
    }

    return {
        fixtures: fetchList(),
    }
}
```

The API

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 77457864,
      "sport_id": 1,
      "league_id": 8,
      "season_id": 19734,
      "type_id": 223,
      "name": "Regular Season",
      "sort_order": 1,
      "finished": false,
      "is_current": true,
      "starting_at": "2022-08-05",
      "ending_at": "2023-05-28",
      "rounds": [
        {
          "id": 274668,
          "sport_id": 1,
          "league_id": 8,
          "season_id": 19734,
          "stage_id": 77457864,
          "name": "1",
          "finished": true,
          "is_current": false,
          "starting_at": "2022-08-05",
          "ending_at": "2022-08-07",
          "fixtures": [
            {
              "id": 18535049,
              "sport_id": 1,
              "league_id": 8,
              "season_id": 19734,
              "stage_id": 77457864,
              "group_id": null,
              "aggregate_id": null,
              "round_id": 274668,
              "state_id": 5,
              "venue_id": 206,
              "name": "Manchester United vs Brighton & Hove Albion",
              "home_score": 1,
              "away_score": 2,
              "starting_at": "2022-08-07 13:00:00",
              "result_info": "Brighton & Hove Albion won after full-time.",
              "leg": "1/1",
              "details": null,
              "length": 90,
              "placeholder": false,
              "last_processed_at": "2022-12-05 09:15:37",
              "starting_at_timestamp": 1659877200,
              "participants": [
                {
                  "id": 14,
                  "sport_id": 1,
                  "country_id": 462,
                  "venue_id": 206,
                  "gender": "male",
                  "name": "Manchester United",
                  "short_code": "MUN",
                  "image_path": "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/teams/14/14.png",
                  "founded": 1878,
                  "type": "domestic",
                  "placeholder": false,
                  "last_played_at": "2022-12-10 17:00:00",
                  "meta": {
                    "location": "home"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "id": 78,
                  "sport_id": 1,
                  "country_id": 462,
                  "venue_id": 480,
                  "gender": "male",
                  "name": "Brighton & Hove Albion",
                  "short_code": "BRH",
                  "image_path": "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/teams/14/78.png",
                  "founded": 1901,
                  "type": "domestic",
                  "placeholder": false,
                  "last_played_at": "2022-12-08 13:00:00",
                  "meta": {
                    "location": "away"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
```

Comment: Use the participants array that’s inside the fixture.  Instead of `teams.short_code` try `fixture.participants.map(p => p.short_code)` - this gives an array of participant short codes within the current fixture.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "dirty" way to do it with {#key}

Comment: Please explain how?

Comment: The {#key} component will watch for changes to the variable you specify inside it and re-render the inner block when the variable changes. In this case, the teams variable. See https://svelte.dev/tutorial/key-blocks for more..